# What does "minus the zero section" mean?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I see a vector bundle obtained from another one by the means of "minus the zero section" in some literature. The concept *zero section* of a vector bundle is found in Section *Sections and locally free sheaves* [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle). But as one can see, this zero section is not something in the vector bundle, but a continuous map. How can I "minus" or subtract a zero section from a vector bundle? Is there an example? Thanks.

Comment: You may want to provide some more context. If I saw someone talking about "a vector bundle minus the zero section", I would assume they meant to remove the zero section as a set from the vector bundle. But then you wind up with an $\Bbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}$-bundle, not another vector bundle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Minus the zero section" means you remove the zero section from the total space. For example, the trivial bundle $X \times \mathbb{R}^n$ over $X$, minus the zero section, is $X \times (\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \})$.